# Get value of class of a DIV using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Question is simple. Not using jQuery... how do I get the value of `class` value in a DIV using regular JavaScript?

Thanks.

Comment: Should've posted at least a little HTML to make your post more clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming this HTML

```
<div id="Target" class="MyClass" />
```

Like This

```
var ElementCssClass = document.getElementById("Target").className;
```

Answer (score 9):

get a reference to the div and use `.className`

```
document.getElementById('someDiv').className
```

Comment: +1 @Jahkr: Or if not `getElementById`, it might be from the list returned by `getElementsByTagName`, or you might navigate to it from another element via `childNodes`, `parentNode`, etc. Details: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/ | http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/ | http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/

Comment: Very odd that the OP accepted the other answer. I guess it was having both the HTML and the JavaScript that made it more useful to them, showed more clearly how they linked up.

Comment: especially since the original answer was "use getAttribute"... I dislike edits on here sometimes.

Comment: @cwolves: Actually, that was a different answer, which the answerer deleted after getting repeatedly downvoted. (It was pointed out to him that it didn't work, and he said "okay, thanks" and then left the answer as it was, didn't fix it, didn't delete it. Hence the downvotes.) Mimisbrunnr said `className` right away.

Comment: @cwolves: I should explain that it's not that I have an obsession and/or incredible memory. There's a rep level where you can see deleted answers. :-)